# Regex - Negate a specific string / sequence of numbers [java]

Tags: java, regex

I'm having problems finding a **RegEx** that negates a specific String. In this case, I'm dealing with **numbers**.

If I want to exclude the number '12' of my group of numbers:

```
[1, 12, 121, 212, 312]
```

How can I do it by using a RegEx? If I use something like **^((?!12).)*$**, it will exclude all the numbers except the "1", because all of them have the '12' pattern.

What would be the rigth expression to use in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^((?!\b12\b).)*$
```

This should do it for you.Word boundaries will enable you to exclude just `12` and not others.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regex for this, you can simply:

```
String num = "[1, 12, 121, 212, 312]".split(",")[1].trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use this,

```
^(?!.*\\b12\\b)\\d+$
```

Negative lookahead at the start asserts that there isn't a number `12` preceded and followed by a word boundary in the strings which are going to match.